# Python custom tkinter gui class/wrapper function doesn't work per instance.

Tags: python, class, user-interface, object, tkinter

I tried to make some sort of wrapper/class to make, making a GUI with tkinter somewhat simpler. I realize this is kind of redundant and it does not make code much prettier or smaller but I just wanted to try if I could do it. Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

class Bysic():
def __init__(self):
    self.app = Tk()

def createButton(self, label, row, col, command, sticky=W):
    self.button = Button(self.app,text=label,command=command)
    self.button.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky=sticky)

def setSize(self, width, height):
    self.app.geometry(str(width)+"x"+str(height))

def setTitle(self, title):
    self.app.title(title)

def createEntry(self, caption, row, col, width=None, defaultValue=None, alignment=W, **options):
    self.entryLabel = Label(self.app, text=caption)
    self.entryLabel.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky=W)
    self.entry = Entry(self.app, **options)
    if defaultValue:
        self.entry.delete(0, END)
        self.entry.insert(0, defaultValue)
    if width:
        self.entry.config(width=width)
    self.entry.grid(row=row, column=col+1, sticky=W)
    return self.entry

def createLabelVar(self, caption, row, col, alignment=W):
    self.labelVar = StringVar()
    self.labelVar.set(caption)
    self.label = Label(self.app, textvar=self.labelVar)
    self.label.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky=alignment)
    return self.labelVar

def createLabel(self, caption, row, col, alignment=W):
    self.staticLabel = Label(self.app, text=caption)
    self.staticLabel.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky=alignment)

def appLoop(self):
    self.app.mainloop()

def appKill(self):
    self.app.destroy()
```

I can now instantiate a 'Bysic'object and spawn GUI elements on it. However one element, the createLabelVar only works on the first gui. Let me demonstrate this.

```
import bysic
x = Bysic()
label = x.createLabelVar("Original text",0,0)
label.set("Overriding text")

a = Bysic()
newLabel = a.createLabelVar("Original text",0,0)
newLabel.set("Override")
```

The first Bysic instance (x) does show the label with the text "Overriding text" however the second Bysic instance (a) doesn't show anything, just a empty tkinter window.

How comes? I mean, x and a are seperate, why does the createLabelVar function work with one instance but not the other?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is not designed to have more than one instance of the `Tk` class. You must create only one, and have only one `mainloop` running.

If you want multiple windows you'll need to create instances of `Toplevel`.